# get text fields that are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, query-string

Let's say that I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="userInfo" name="first_name1" value="First name 1" />
    <input type="text" class="userInfo" name="first_name2" value="First name 2" />
</div>

<div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="userInfo" name="first_name3" value="First name 3" />
    <input type="text" class="userInfo" name="first_name4" value="First name 4" />
</div>
```

How do I get all the text fields that are not empty when the user clicks on a button with jQuery?

Once I get them, I want to construct a key-value pair string (concatenated with &) to be sent as parameter to a URL for example:

```
"first_name1='First name 1&first_name2=First name 2'....
```

Comment: What do you want to do with them once you have them?

Comment: See edited question @Andrew Bone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find all the `input` elements that contain values:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tvcac1em/)

```
var $fieldsWithValues = $('input').filter(function () {
    return this.value;
});
```

---

Based on your edit, you can construct the query string by using the [`$.param()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ph255uuc/)

```
var params = {};
var $fieldsWithValues = $('input').filter(function () {
    return this.value.trim();
}).each(function () {
    params[this.name] = this.value;
});

console.log($.param(params));
```

The above would log:

```
"first_name1=First+name+1&first_name2=First+name+2&first_name3=First+name+3&first_name4=First+name+4"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

  $("#yourButtonId").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

      var emptyItems=[];
      var items = $("input.userInfo");

      $.each(items,function(i,k){
         var item =$(this);
         if(item.val()!="")
         {
           emptyItems.push(item.attr("name"));
         }
     })
     console.log(emptyItems);        
   })

})
```

Now `emptyItems` will have the names of non empty textboxes

Working sample [here](http://jsbin.com/pogozetijo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a quick selector for this where jQuery hides all the work. You will need to find inputs and then loop over them and check their values.

```
var inputsWithValue = $('input').filter(
    function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }
);
```